# How do I solve this problem 'Symfony 5.4 : Too few parameters: the query defines 2 parameters but you only bound 1'?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, dql, symfony5

I want to load all the 'Interns'(Stagiaires) that are to be paid in 'Payment'(Bordereaus).I want to do that by selecting a date interval and passing attributes of Interns through them to select only those who's Internship ends in the date interval.
'Interns' and 'Payment' don't have a relationship but there is a table 'Interns_Payment'(Bordereau_stagiaire) which is linked to both tables. I want to do it through the repository and then load it in the 'edit' of my PaymentController. I'm new to symfnony

I wrote this query in my Payment(Bordereau)Repository

```php
    public function findByDate(Bordereau $bordereau){
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('bo');

       return $query->select('bo', 'bord_stag', 'st')
        ->leftJoin('bo.bordereauStagiaire', 'bord_stag')
        ->leftJoin('bord_stag.stagiaire', 'st')
        ->andWhere('st.finStage >= IN(:dateDebut)')
        ->andWhere('st.finStage <= IN(:dateFin)')
        ->andWhere('st.isDeleted = IN(:delete)')
        ->setParameter('delete', false)
        ->setParameter('dateFin', $bordereau->dateFin)
        ->setParameter('dateDebut', $bordereau->dateDebut)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
        ;
        
    }
```

and this is my Payment(Bordereau) edit function in my controller

```php
    #[Route('/{id}/edit', name: 'app_bordereau_edit', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
    public function edit(Request $request, Bordereau $bordereau, BordereauRepository $bordereauRepo): Response
    {
        $formBordereau = $this->createForm(BordereauEditType::class, $bordereau);
        $formBordereau->handleRequest($request);

        if ($formBordereau->isSubmitted() && $formBordereau->isValid()) {
            $bordereauRepo->save($bordereau, true);
            dd($bordereau);
            
            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_bordereau_index', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
        }
        
        return $this->renderForm('bordereau/edit.html.twig', [
            'bordereau' => $bordereau,
            'form' => $formBordereau,
        ]);
    }
```

I was expecting to get the result by checking with a `dd($bordereauRepository);` but I instead got this result.

I've searched over similar issues concerning Too few parameters in query but could not succeed in finding a solution.

**EDIT**

I added the setParamaters of dateDebut and dateFin. But I can't access it.

Should I create a custom form of bordereau?

**EDIT2**

This is my new DQL function

```php
public function findByDate(BordereauEditModel $bordereau, bool $isDeleted = false){
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('bo');

        $query
        ->select('bo', 'bord_stag', 'st')
        ->leftJoin('bo.bordereauStagiaire', 'bord_stag')
        ->leftJoin('bord_stag.stagiaire', 'st')
        ->andWhere('st.isDeleted = :delete')
        ->setParameter('delete', $isDeleted);

        if ($bordereau->dateDebut) {
            $query->andWhere('st.finStage <= :dateDebut')
            ->setParameter('dateDebut', $bordereau->dateDebut->format('Y-m-d'));
        }

        if ($bordereau->dateFin) {
            $query->andWhere('st.finStage <= :dateFin')
            ->setParameter('dateFin', $bordereau->dateFin->format('Y-m-d'));
        }
        
        $query
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
        ;
        
    }
```

It prints the result with the static parameters I've set. But with dynamic ones it doesn't.

Also I created a Model `BordereauEditModel` and a custom form from `BordereauEditType`

This is my `edit` function in `BordereauController`

```php
    #[Route('/{id}/edit', name: 'app_bordereau_edit', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
    public function edit(Request $request, Bordereau $bordereau, BordereauRepository $bordereauRepository, BordereauEditModel $bordereauEdit): Response
    {
        $bordereauEdit = new BordereauEditModel();

        $formBordereau = $this->createForm(BordereauEditType::class, $bordereauEdit);
        $formBordereau->handleRequest($request);

        if ($formBordereau->isSubmitted() && $formBordereau->isValid()) {
            
            $bordereauRepository->findByDate($bordereauEdit);
            $bordereauRepository->save($bordereau, true);
            dd($bordereauRepository);
            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_bordereau_index', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
        }
        
        return $this->renderForm('bordereau/edit.html.twig', [
            'bordereau' => $bordereau,
            'form' => $formBordereau,
        ]);
    }
```

When I try to load the dynamic ones it says 'call to a member function format() on null' . I don't know if this is another issue and I should remove it from here (ie as a paragraph in the main post so that people won't be confused)

Call to a member function format() on null -> Solved

Comment: looking at that piece of PHP/SQL there are 3 placeholders (`:dateDebut`,`:dateFin`,`:delete`) and only a single call to `setParameter` to set `delete`. I've never used Symphony but I would expect 3 calls to `setParameter` for that sql? I would also guess that those date variables should be passed as arguments to that method?

Comment: Ok thanks prof I'll try to implement that and see what it does

Comment: `$bordereauRepository->findByDate();`need the argument `$bordereauRepository->findByDate($bordereau);`

Comment: I added it in the code I forgot to post in the update. Thanks

Comment: does it solved your problem?

Comment: you can not check with `dd($bordereauRepository);` because this is the repository. To `dd` the result, you can use `dd($bordereauRepository->findByDate($bordereau));` or assign this result to variable and `dd` this variable. Also try to assign an array value with one element to the placeholder, since it's an `IN` clause.

Comment: @Ralda00 Why are you trying to use the IN clause at all? Even if your debut and fin dates are arrays it's not going to give you the sort of ranges that you want.  And hardcoding delete to false is a bit bizarre.  Maybe spend some time in a sql console and just get your query to work manually before trying to get fancy.

Comment: @FatalError no it didn't ?

Comment: @Raphael I did it before but couldn't because of the error

Comment: Actually all this `IN` doesn't make any sense. It is not working with the operators, since this will check for equality in the given values. Remove these and go either with `=`, `<=` and `>=` or try using the `expressionBuilder`, which is available in your `entityManager` via `$this->entityManager->getExpressionBuilder()`.

Comment: @Raphael I removed the `IN`

Comment: @Cerad this is my SQL query `SELECT * FROM stagiaire JOIN bordereau_stagiaire ON stagiaire.id = bordereau_stagiaire.stagiaire_id JOIN bordereau ON bordereau_id = bordereau_stagiaire.bordereau_id WHERE stagiaire.fin_stage >= bordereau.date_debut AND WHERE stagiaire.fin_stage <= bordereau.date_fin`

Comment: Great.  Consider updating your question to show your latest DQL query.  I assume it is not working but hopefully the error message has changed?  And if you have not already, try creating a console command to test your query without having to refresh your browser.  Doing so often helps to pin down errors.

Comment: Thank you very much to all of you for your help

Comment: The new error `call to a member function format() on null` comes from your object `$bordereau`. Make sure, both, the `dateFin` and `dateDebut` have a valid value, not `null`. That's the reason, it's working with the static date, but you haven't assigned a valid value to at least one of these date variables of `$bordereau`.

Comment: Ok thanks. There's no error on the repo I'll post the edit

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `IN` from the conditions. If you want to check with `IN`, you can not use comparison operators.

```php
public function findByDate(Bordereau $bordereau){
   $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('bo');

   return $query->select('bo', 'bord_stag', 'st')
    ->leftJoin('bo.bordereauStagiaire', 'bord_stag')
    ->leftJoin('bord_stag.stagiaire', 'st')
    ->andWhere('st.finStage >= :dateDebut')
    ->andWhere('st.finStage <= :dateFin')
    ->andWhere('st.isDeleted = :delete')
    ->setParameter('delete', false)
    ->setParameter('dateFin', $bordereau->dateFin)
    ->setParameter('dateDebut', $bordereau->dateDebut)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult()
    ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I had done that already I didn't make the update soon enough. My apologies